# Bold math in title but not in TOC

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, titles, bold

I've seen similar problems around but I haven't been able to solve mine.

Basically, I have a bold math in section title but I don't want it to be bold in TOC as in figures below.

[image: Figure 1]

[image: Figure 2]

My code for these is:

```
\section{L\texorpdfstring{\textsubscript{L1} = 1.2\boldmath{$H$}}{First magnet}}\label{1st_magnet}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which documentclass are you using?  It would be nice if you could add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. I'm new to this. Anyways, I'm using book class.
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\boldmath}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for \texorpdfstring

\setcounter{chapter}{4}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{\texorpdfstring{$L_\text{L1} = \SI{1.2}{\henry}$}{First magnet}}
\label{1st_magnet}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get a bunch of errors if I include \titleformat command in my preamble. I suddenly get a missing \begin{document}. - __ -

Comment: Didn't you forget the `*` at the end of `\titleformat*{`? It's very important because it's the `short` version of `\titleformat` (which requires 5 mandatory arguments in its long version).

Comment: I tried both with * and without and it doesn't work.

Comment: Even  just the code I posted?

Comment: Using siunitx and {\sisetup{detect-weight=true, detect-family=true}} finally did it. Thanks for ideas and help!

Comment: Works fine here as posted. But how about the very same for the **Chapter title**? Being presumably about _section_ titles, titlesec does not seem to like `\titleformat*{\chapter}{\bfseries\boldmath}` at all.

Comment: @schremmer: Normally, there should be no problem. Did you change the class when you tried with `\chapter`? The article class doesn't  define `\chapter`.

Comment: It's `book` and it all compiles ok. (Except that the size of section titles has now shrunk to, I believe, `tiny`.) So, now two (very small) problems. I wouldn't mind them fixed but I sure can live with these two.

Comment: I have a MWE but I have no idea how to bring it here.

Comment: You can ask a new question and post the code  clicking on the button `{}` in the toolbar  to insert code.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `sectsty` package to apply `\boldmath` to all sections using `\allsectionsfont{\boldmath}`.  See how I don't have to use explicit `\boldmath` in the section header anymore.

Furthermore, `\boldmath` does not take an argument but is a font switch.  To see what I mean compare `\boldmath{$a$} $b$` and `{\boldmath $a$} $b$`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\boldmath}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for \texorpdfstring
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{L\texorpdfstring{\textsubscript{L1} = 1.2$H$}{First magnet}}
\label{1st_magnet}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Christian suggested in the comments it is much better to use a package for typesetting units.  Just like Christian I also suggest `siunitx` for that matter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\boldmath}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for \texorpdfstring
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{\texorpdfstring{$L_{\text{L1}} = \SI{1.2}{\henry}$}{First magnet}}
\label{1st_magnet}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can ignore this solution, but others might be interested in how to do it with ConTeXt.

```
\setupinteraction[state=start]
\placebookmarks[section]

\setuphead[section][style=bold]

\starttext

\placecontent

\startsection
  [
    title={$L_{\tf L1} = \unit{1.2 henry}$},
    bookmark={First magnet},
    reference=1st_magnet,
  ]
\stopsection

\stoptext
```

Comment: For the non-ConTeXt solution I suggest the usage of `siunitx` package to typeset the inductance value

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies. This seems neat but for some reason I can't install sectsty package. :/

Comment: I tried installing it but I can't run .ins file and I cannot make a local texmf tree. No idea how to do it even if I follow the steps.

Comment: @HenriMenke I know how to add packages using MikTeX but I was getting a 404 server error so I checked that one and I synchronized it and I managed to install the package even though I did not use it finally. Thanks anyways!

Comment: How to use the `\allsectionsfont` command for bold math using `unicode-math`? kpfonts-otf provides a bold math font, but neither `\allsectionsfont{\boldmath}`  nor `\allsectionsfont{\mathversion{bold}}` work.