# Problems with bold math in title via titlesec

Tags: titlesec

I wanted to have [Bold math in title but not in TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323455/bold-math-in-title-but-not-in-toc) and I chose Bernard's solution with `titlesec` which the document was already heavily using. It worked except for *two* problems:

--I was unable to make it work for Chapter as `\titleformat*{\chapter}{\bfseries\boldmath}` causes an error.

--The size of section titles has now shrunk to, I believe, `tiny`and adding `\big` causes an error.

(An hour ago, I had a third one but that was because I can't read!)

I think the issue is complicated by all the reference machinery I have. So, here it is in a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amsbsy} 
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fixmath}    

\usepackage{titlesec} 
    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}
%   \titleformat*{\chapter}{\bfseries\boldmath}%<<==BERNARD This causes an error
    \titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\boldmath}%<<==BERNARD This shrinks titles
    \usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}%<<<<<<<=======BERNARD
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
    \titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries\filright}{\contentslabel[\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{6pc}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{2pt}]%
    \newcommand\xquad{\hspace*{0.4em plus .2em minus .2em}}%
    \titlecontents*{p-section}[0pt]{\filright\small}{}{}{, \thecontentspage}[\xquad\textbullet\xquad][.]%
    \newcommand{\ChapterToc}{\startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{}\vspace{10mm}}%
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs  \hspace{10mm}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}% 
    \tcbuselibrary{%Begin load libraries for tcolorbox  
        xparse,%
            }%End load libraries for tcolorbox      
\usepackage{makeidx} %The \imakeindex does not work
        \makeindex

    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
%=============== Begin the Heiko Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%=============== End the Heiko Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' which loads showidx
    \hypersetup{%begin colors
                   colorlinks,
                   linkcolor={red!50!black},
                }%end colors

\usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
    \Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
    \newcommand{\titleref}{\nameref}%displays TITLE of refered item
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs

%========================== Begin math in Showindex
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
%========================== End math in Showindex
%========================== Begin Andrew code for ref to indexed words as edited Oct 27 at 17:24
    \newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{\phantomsection%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
   \else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
    }%
%========================== End Andrew code for ref to indexed words as edited Oct 27 at 17:24
%===Begin DEX original
    \newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2}%
   % (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
   \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2}%
   %(\Cpageref{ind:#1})%
   \fi%
}%
%%===End DEX original
%============== Begin To make Cpageref work with INDEX
\newcommand{\PGX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}%
   \relax%
%   \hyperref[ind:#2]{#2}%
    \Cpageref{ind:#2}%
   \else%
%   \hyperref[ind:#1]{#2}%
   \Cpageref{ind:#1}%
   \fi%
}%
%============== End To make Cpageref work with INDEX.
\begin{document}
         \tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter Title emboldens % 
0 and $\infty$ but not $0$ nor $x_{0}$ nor $MathText$%
}%
\label{1-0-0}
    \ChapterToc
Some text
 with an indexed \textbf{word}\INDEX[]{word} and indexed math $\boldsymbol{x_{0}}$\INDEX[x0]{$x_{0}$}:

\section{Section Title emboldens %
 0 and $\infty$ as well as $0$ and $x_{0}$ and $MathText$%
 }%
 \label{1-1-0}
 A bit more text and finally:


\subsection{%
Subsection Title emboldens %
0 and $\infty$ %
but not $0$ nor $x_{0}$ nor $MathText$. %
However %
$\boldsymbol{MathText}$, %
$\boldsymbol{x_{0}}$ and %
$\bm{0}$ all work.%
}%
\label{1-2-1}
Plus just a tiny little bit of text%
 with a referenced \DEX[word]{word} %
which was indexed in \Cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0} on \Cpageref{1-0-0}

    \phantomsection%otherwise, clicking on index in toc gets to GNU
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}   
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: A general solution is `\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother` which causes `\bfseries` to also do `\boldmath`

Comment: Generally you should ask on only one question at a time.  Your posting contains several.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I will try your first suggestion a bit later but entering `\boldsymbol`by hand caused an error. Also, I think that all three issues are strongly related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that `\titleformat*` cannot be applied to `\chapter`. You can instead patch `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`, actually the aliases to them defined by `titlesec`. Also, you need to state the font size for `\section`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor} 

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{amsbsy} 
\usepackage{amssymb}    
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fixmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{makeidx} %The \imakeindex does not work
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttl@save@mkchap}
  {\huge\bfseries}
  {\huge\bfseries\boldmath}
  {}{\ddt}
\patchcmd{\ttl@save@mkchap}
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {\Huge\bfseries\boldmath}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\ttl@save@mkschap}
  {\Huge\bfseries}
  {\Huge\bfseries\boldmath}
  {}{}

\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries\boldmath}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\bfseries}
  {\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}
  {1mm}
  {}

\titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]
  {\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries\boldmath\filright}
  {\contentslabel[\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{6pc}}
  {}
  {\hfill\contentspage}
  [\addvspace{2pt}]

\newcommand\xquad{\hspace*{0.4em plus .2em minus .2em}}%

\titlecontents*{p-section}[0pt]
  {\filright\small}
  {}
  {}
  {, \thecontentspage}
  [\xquad\textbullet\xquad]
  [.]

\newcommand{\ChapterToc}{%
  \startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{}\vspace{10mm}%
}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs  \hspace{10mm}

\tcbuselibrary{%Begin load libraries for tcolorbox  
  xparse,%
}%End load libraries for tcolorbox      
\makeindex

%=============== Begin the Heiko Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%=============== End the Heiko Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' which loads showidx
    \hypersetup{%begin colors
                   colorlinks,
                   linkcolor={red!50!black},
                }%end colors

\usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
    \Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
    \newcommand{\titleref}{\nameref}%displays TITLE of refered item
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs

%========================== Begin math in Showindex
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
%========================== End math in Showindex
%========================== Begin Andrew code for ref to indexed words as edited Oct 27 at 17:24
    \newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{\phantomsection%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
   \else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
    }%
%========================== End Andrew code for ref to indexed words as edited Oct 27 at 17:24
%===Begin DEX original
    \newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2}%
   % (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
   \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2}%
   %(\Cpageref{ind:#1})%
   \fi%
}%
%%===End DEX original
%============== Begin To make Cpageref work with INDEX
\newcommand{\PGX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}%
   \relax%
%   \hyperref[ind:#2]{#2}%
    \Cpageref{ind:#2}%
   \else%
%   \hyperref[ind:#1]{#2}%
   \Cpageref{ind:#1}%
   \fi%
}%
%============== End To make Cpageref work with INDEX.
\begin{document}
         \tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter Title emboldens % 
0 and $\infty$ but not $0$ nor $x_{0}$ nor $MathText$%
}%
\label{1-0-0}
    \ChapterToc
Some text
 with an indexed \textbf{word}\INDEX[]{word} and indexed math $\boldsymbol{x_{0}}$\INDEX[x0]{$x_{0}$}:

\section{Section Title emboldens %
 0 and $\infty$ as well as $0$ and $x_{0}$ and $MathText$%
 }%
 \label{1-1-0}
 A bit more text and finally:


\subsection{%
Subsection Title emboldens %
0 and $\infty$ %
but not $0$ nor $x_{0}$ nor $MathText$. %
However %
$\boldsymbol{MathText}$, %
$\boldsymbol{x_{0}}$ and %
$\bm{0}$ all work.%
}%
\label{1-2-1}
Plus just a tiny little bit of text%
 with a referenced \DEX[word]{word} %
which was indexed in \Cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0} on \Cpageref{1-0-0}

    \phantomsection%otherwise, clicking on index in toc gets to GNU
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}   
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Of course. (But why does the `titlesec` doc give `big` instead of `Large`???) Thanks.

Comment: @schremmer I'm not sure what `big` you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was just grumbling because the titlesec doc says on page 2: ""big small medium tiny Set the the size of titles." and I felt like an idiot as I should have known better. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To amplify a little on my comment, just adding

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother
```

to your code does not produce errors and makes mathematics bold whenever you request the text to be bold:

[image: Sample output]

(Full document code below.)

Of course it should be used with care, as one needs to decide what should be done if the mathematics already contains individual `\mathbf` symbols, but your own attempt has a similar caveat.

As I said in my comment the sizing issues etc. are separate problems.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fixmath}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\bfseries{\boldmath}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\normalfont\bfseries}{\hspace{10mm}\arabic{subsection}.}{1mm}{}{}
%   \titleformat*{\chapter}{\bfseries\boldmath}%<<==BERNARD This causes an error
    \titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\boldmath}%<<==BERNARD This shrinks titles
    \usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}%<<<<<<<=======BERNARD
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
    \titlecontents{chapter}[6pc]{\addvspace{1pc}\bfseries\filright}{\contentslabel[\chaptername\ \thecontentslabel]{6pc}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\addvspace{2pt}]%
    \newcommand\xquad{\hspace*{0.4em plus .2em minus .2em}}%
    \titlecontents*{p-section}[0pt]{\filright\small}{}{}{, \thecontentspage}[\xquad\textbullet\xquad][.]%
    \newcommand{\ChapterToc}{\startcontents[chapters]\printcontents[chapters]{p-}{1}{}\vspace{10mm}}%
        \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs  \hspace{10mm}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
    \tcbuselibrary{%Begin load libraries for tcolorbox
        xparse,%
            }%End load libraries for tcolorbox
\usepackage{makeidx} %The \imakeindex does not work
        \makeindex

    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
%=============== Begin the Heiko Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' which loads showidx
\makeatletter
\ifHy@hyperindex
  \def\HyInd@ParenLeft{(}%
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex
  \let\HyInd@showidx\@empty
% Hook in \HyInd@@wrindex for package showidx
  \def\HyInd@showidx#1{%
    \@showidx{#1}%
    \if@nobreak
      \ifvmode
        \nobrak
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
% Load package showidx
  \let\siOrg@makeindex\makeindex
  \let\siOrg@@index\@index
  \let\siOrg@@wrindex\@wrindex
  \let\siOrg@index\index
  \RequirePackage{showidx}
  \let\makeindex\siOrg@makeindex
  \let\@index\siOrg@@index
  \let\@wrindex\siOrg@@wrindex
  \let\index\siOrg@index
% rest of hyperref part
  \@ifpackageloaded{multind}{%
    \let\HyInd@org@wrindex\@wrindex
    \def\@wrindex#1#2{\HyInd@@wrindex{#1}#2||\\}%
    \def\HyInd@@wrindex#1#2|#3|#4\\{%
      \ifx\\#3\\%
        \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|hyperpage}%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#3}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3hyperpage}%
        \else
          \HyInd@org@wrindex{#1}{#2|#3}%
        \fi
      \fi
    }%
  }{%
    \def\@wrindex#1{\@@wrindex#1||\\}
    \def\@@wrindex#1|#2|#3\\{%
      \ifx\\#2\\%
        \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
          \string\indexentry{#1|hyperpage}{\thepage}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\Hy@temp@A{#2}%
        \ifx\Hy@temp@A\HyInd@ParenLeft
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
             \string\indexentry{#1|#2hyperpage}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \else
          \protected@write\@indexfile{}{%
            \string\indexentry{#1|#2}{\thepage}%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
      \endgroup
      \HyInd@showidx{#1}%
      \@esphack
    }%
  }%
\fi
\makeatother
%=============== End the Heiko Oberdiek ``quick and dirty hack'' which loads showidx
    \hypersetup{%begin colors
                   colorlinks,
                   linkcolor={red!50!black},
                }%end colors

\usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
    \Crefname{subsection}{Subsection}{Subsections}
    \newcommand{\titleref}{\nameref}%displays TITLE of refered item
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}% <- only parts, chapters and sections in tocs

%========================== Begin math in Showindex
\let\oldopenparen\(
\let\oldcloseparen\)
\def\({\protect\oldopenparen}
\def\){\protect\oldcloseparen}
%========================== End math in Showindex
%========================== Begin Andrew code for ref to indexed words as edited Oct 27 at 17:24
    \newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{\phantomsection%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
   \else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
    }%
%========================== End Andrew code for ref to indexed words as edited Oct 27 at 17:24
%===Begin DEX original
    \newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2}%
   % (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
   \else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2}%
   %(\Cpageref{ind:#1})%
   \fi%
}%
%%===End DEX original
%============== Begin To make Cpageref work with INDEX
\newcommand{\PGX}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}%
   \relax%
%   \hyperref[ind:#2]{#2}%
    \Cpageref{ind:#2}%
   \else%
%   \hyperref[ind:#1]{#2}%
   \Cpageref{ind:#1}%
   \fi%
}%
%============== End To make Cpageref work with INDEX.
\begin{document}
         \tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter Title emboldens %
0 and $\infty$ but not $0$ nor $x_{0}$ nor $MathText$%
}%
\label{1-0-0}
    \ChapterToc
Some text
 with an indexed \textbf{word}\INDEX[]{word} and indexed math $\boldsymbol{x_{0}}$\INDEX[x0]{$x_{0}$}:

\section{Section Title emboldens %
 0 and $\infty$ as well as $0$ and $x_{0}$ and $MathText$%
 }%
 \label{1-1-0}
 A bit more text and finally:


\subsection{%
Subsection Title emboldens %
0 and $\infty$ %
but not $0$ nor $x_{0}$ nor $MathText$. %
However %
$\boldsymbol{MathText}$, %
$\boldsymbol{x_{0}}$ and %
$\bm{0}$ all work.%
}%
\label{1-2-1}
Plus just a tiny little bit of text%
 with a referenced \DEX[word]{word} %
which was indexed in \Cref{1-0-0} \nameref{1-0-0} on \Cpageref{1-0-0}

    \phantomsection%otherwise, clicking on index in toc gets to GNU
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Re size. I agree of course but the size issue came about only as I was trying to solve the math boldface issue. Unfortunately I have to push LaTeX way beyond the usual and I am programming impaired to begin with.